How to run and stop the same function a number of times in a thread?
I have written a program that has GUI loop (while run loop) and within that loop another process is started in a separate thread. Function make_measurement is executed which reads data from a measurement device. Thread starts if it is not alive. The measurement loop in a thread can be stopped by the user (using a stop button), which is simulated in the example code by checking condition x[0]==11. After running the code both loops (GUI loop and loop within make_measurement function) execute smoothly to the moment when the thread is stopped. GUI loop is still running and because thread is not alive it wants to start the thread again, bu a thread can't be started twice. In my program User can start and stop make_measurement many times while GUI loop still runs. I suppose I have to create new thread after every start/stop sequence, but how to code it?
This is aqan example code:

from threading import Thread, Event
from time import sleep

def make_measurement(n, x):
    i=n
    while i>0:
        sleep(0.5)
        i=i-1
        x[0]=i

        if event.is_set():
            break


run=True

j=0

x=[0]
event=Event()
t=Thread(target=make_measurement, args=(20,x,))

#GUI loop
while run:
    sleep(0.2)
    #start measurement thread within loop
    if not t.is_alive():
        t.start()
        print("Start")
    j=j+1
    print("iteration: " +str(j), " number: " + str(x[0]))
    if x[0]==11:
        event.set()

First I have expected that You can start and stop the same thread many times.

The objective seems to be to stop taking measurements and then restart under some condition. You could use a single thread for this with two events - i.e., one to tell the thread to take measurements (or not) and the other to tell it when to stop altogether. If the thread is running but not taking measurements, just wait on the appropriate event.
You could adapt the following to suit your needs:
from threading import Thread, Event
from queue import Queue
from random import random
from time import sleep, time

def takeMeasurements(run, measure, q):
    while run.is_set():
        if measure.is_set():
            print("Taking measurement")
            q.put(random())
        else:
            print("Not measuring")
        sleep(1)
    print("Thread terminating")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # initial state of the events is that the thread should run AND take measurements
    (threadRun := Event()).set()
    (threadMeasure := Event()).set()
    queue = Queue()
    (t := Thread(target=takeMeasurements, args=[threadRun, threadMeasure, queue])).start()
    # thread is now running and taking measurements
    # run loop for approximately 10 seconds
    start = time()
    while time() - start < 10:
        m = queue.get()
        print(f"Measurement = {m}")
        threadMeasure.clear() # will stop measurements
        sleep(2)
        threadMeasure.set() # restart taking measurements
    threadRun.clear()
    t.join()


Thanks a lot. I do not understand this code fully, but to extent I can use this in my app.
